# Cant Edit Jtextfield after selected row at jtable

Tags: java, netbeans

i dont understand why i cant edit the jtextfield after i select some row in my jtable. i just can see the data was correct retrive but cant edit or update the data in jtext field.

```
 private void T_REQMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
            int sel = T_REQ.getSelectedRow();
        
          
           String id = (String) T_REQ.getValueAt(sel, 0);
           NOREQ.setText(id);
           try {
                 String sql = "select * from T_REQUESTBD where IDREQUEST = '"+id+"'order by IDREQUEST DESC";
                 st =  con.createStatement();
                 rs =st.executeQuery(sql);
               while (rs.next()) {
                TableModel model = T_REQ.getModel();
                Object[] o = new Object[8];
                o[0] = rs.getString("IDREQUEST");
                o[1] = rs.getString("NO_UNIT");
                o[2] = rs.getString("JENISBD");
                o[3] = rs.getString("HMAWAL");
                o[4] = rs.getString("HMBD");
                o[5] = rs.getString("REMARKSBD");
                o[6] = rs.getString("LOG_TIME");
                o[7] = rs.getString("LOGTGL");
                
                TX_UNIT.setText(rs.getString("NO_UNIT"));
                JENIS.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("JENISBD"));
                HMAWAL.setText(rs.getString("HMAWAL"));
                HMBD.setText(rs.getString("HMBD"));
                REMARKS.setText(rs.getString("REMARKSBD"));
                String jam = JAM.getText();
                String tgl1 = TANGGAL.getText();
                EDIT.setVisible(true);
                DELETE.setVisible(true);
              }
           }catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Gagal Di Simpan,error : "+e);
           }
           
           
           
    }  


 private void CREATEActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    String id = NOREQ.getText();
    String unit = TX_UNIT.getText();
    String jenis = (String) JENIS.getSelectedItem();
    String awal = HMAWAL.getText();
    String hmbd = HMBD.getText();
    String marks = REMARKS.getText();
    String jam = JAM.getText();
    String tgl1 = TANGGAL.getText();
   
        try {
            con = KONEK.getConnection();
            String sql = "insert into T_REQUESTBD values('"+id+"',"
                    + "'"+unit+"',"
                    + "'"+jenis+"',"
                    + "'"+awal+"',"
                    + "'"+hmbd+"',"
                    + "'"+marks+"',"
                    + "'"+jam+"',"
                    + "'"+tgl1+"')";
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
            if(rs.next()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Berhasil Ditambahkan");
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) T_REQ.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
            data();
            bersih();
            tombol();
            }else {
                var x = JENIS.getSelectedIndex();
                if (x == 0){
                    rs = st.executeQuery(null);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Gagal Di Simpan,error ");
                }
            }
            
        }catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Gagal Di Simpan,error : "+e);
        }finally{
             
             autoid();
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is but a small portion of the GUI builder generated code.  We can't just look at code and find problems.  We need a [mre] that we can run in our IDE and test, test, test.

Comment: This looks to be one of your first questions asked on this site, and I think that I speak for all in welcoming you to Stack Overflow. This site works differently from other help sites in that first and foremost, it is a question and answer site, one that is curated by site users. I suggest that you check the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) links in that order to get a feeling of how this site works and how to best use this site.

Comment: thankyou sir, the problem is solve now, i just start make a new Jform and copy paste the the element and the code from the form before into the new ones and it solve. and sorry for the abstract question i post, yes, cause this is my first post in here. Thankyou sir.